# Internal microphone not working in Google talk

Tags: microphone, google-talk

My laptop is Lenovo T400, which has an internal microphone. My OS is Ubuntu 10.10. My browser is Firefox 11.0.

The internal microphone works fine, because I can use it to record my voice using Audaciy.

However, in Google talk, I have choose "Internal Audio Analog Stereo" in "Settings -> Voice and video chat -> Microphone:". But when I click "Verify your settings", it doesn't work. Neither can I speak to others using Google Talk. I wonder why?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may need to check your sound settings using the Ubuntu System Settings - ensure you device shows up. You would look under the Input Tab.

[image]

If it says Analog Microphone like mine does you will need to change it to 'Internal Microphone'. You may also have to uncheck 'mute' or increase the input volume.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. But this didnt work for me

Comment: Fawkes5 - you may want to post your own question then so we can get more details about your specific situation.